# JQuery UI size effect won't begin from bottom right origin point

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the JQuery UI effect 'size' to scale up 3 separate divs on a page.  The idea is there is 1 div on the left and two divs on the right.  The left div scales up beginning from top left, the top right div scales up beginning at top right while the bottom right div *should* scale up from the bottom right - however it is scaling up beginning at top right.

You can see where I'm at using the following link.

http://www.fusionbureau.com/sh-test/

All the divs start with a width and height of zero and are scaled up to the size specified in the JQuery.  The left div and the top right div are just floated left and right respectively.  The bottom right div is enclosed in a container that is absolutely positioned and the div is floated to the right.  I've tried alternatives such as floating the container and absolutely positioning the contained div but after it's scaled up it always ends up in the wrong place.  The size effect is also wrong in this case - beginning at top right.

Here is the HTML, CSS and Jquery.

HTML

```
<div id="index-container">
<div id="content-left">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor amet</p>
<span><a href="1">1</a> <a href="2">2</a> <a href="3">3</a> <a href="4">4</a></span>
</div>
<div id="content-topright"><p>Our stories</p></div>
<div id="content-bottomright-wrapper">
<div id="content-bottomright">
    <p>blah</p>
</div>    
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#index-container{
position:relative;  
height:544px;
width:940px;
color:#fff;
}
#content-left{
top:0;
left:0;
width:0;
height:0;
position:relative;
float:left;
background-image:url('images/wall.jpg');
background-color:#000;
}
#content-topright{
float:right;
width:0;
height:0;
position:relative;  
background-color:#058625;
}
#content-bottomright-wrapper{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:574px;
padding:0;
width:364px;
height:262px;
}
#content-bottomright{
float:right;
padding:0;
width:0;
height:0;
position:relative;
background-color:#ccc;
margin:0 auto !important;
}
```

JQuery

```
function displayBoxes(){    
var fadeinspeed = 600;
var transitiondelay = 400;
var content_left_height = "544px";
var content_left_width = "555px";
var content_topr_height = "262px";
var content_topr_width = "364px";
var content_botr_height = "262px";
var content_botr_width = "364px";

$('#content-left').children().hide();
$('#content-topright').children().hide();
$('#content-bottomright').children().hide();
$('#content-left').effect('size', { to: { width: content_left_width, height: content_left_height }, origin: ['top','left'] ,scale: 'box'}, fadeinspeed, function () { fadeinKids('#content-left')});
$('#content-topright').delay(transitiondelay).effect('size', { to: { width: content_topr_width, height: content_topr_height }, origin: ['top','right'] ,scale: 'box'}, fadeinspeed, function () { fadeinKids('#content-topright')});
$('#content-bottomright').delay(transitiondelay*2).effect('size', { to: { width: content_botr_width, height: content_botr_height }, origin: ['bottom','right'] ,scale: 'both'}, fadeinspeed, function () { fadeinKids('#content-bottomright')});
};

function fadeinKids(parentObj){
var kids = $(parentObj).children(); 
var myitems = kids.hide();  
var i = 0; 
      (function displayKid() {  
         myitems.eq(i++).fadeIn('', displayKid);  
      })();
};
```

The fadeinkids function can be ignored - this is just for fading in elements within the divs after they have reached full size.

It seems like I should be positioning it at the bottom right of the containing div, but this causes the effect to happen with the div's top left corner at the bottom right corner of the containing div and then when it's at full size it jumps into place.

Any help or advice would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on JQuery UI.  Below is how I did it - just the code for the bottom right block that grows from the bottom right of the element to the top left.

HTML

```
<div id="content-bottomright-wrapper">
<div id="content-bottomright">
<img src="images/home/map.png">
</div>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
#content-bottomright-wrapper{
display:block;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:574px;
padding:0;
width:364px;
height:262px;
margin:0 !important;
}
#content-bottomright{
padding:0;
width:0;
height:0;
position:relative;
background-color:#ccc;
}
```

Javascript (JQuery)

```
function scaleReverse(item,scaleSpeed,scaleDelay,mycallback){
    scaleDelay = scaleDelay || 0;
    $(item).height(0);
    $(item).width(0);   
    var daddy = $(item).parent();
    var targetheight = daddy.height();
    var targetwidth = daddy.width();
    $(item).css("margin-top",targetheight);
    $(item).css("margin-left",targetwidth);
    $(item).delay(scaleDelay).animate({
    marginLeft: 0,
    marginTop: 0,
    width: targetwidth,
    height: targetheight
    }, scaleSpeed,function () {if (typeof mycallback == "function") mycallback()});
}

    // call the function!
    scaleReverse('#content-bottomright',600,800,function () {$('#content-bottomright').children().fadeIn()});
```

It would be pretty easy to turn this into a plug-in. If I have more time I will.